# How to populate edit form fields in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a problem in populating edit form fields in my first Laravel 5.3 application. In examples I have found online, they have used Form facade to do it. However, I prefer to use plain html.

This is my controller action

```
public function edit()
{
    $profile = Profile::find(Auth::user()->id);
    return  view('profile.edit', ['profile' => $profile]);
}
```

In my view file I have a form like this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('profile/update') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
...
</form>
```

Problem is, above input field is not populated with the value of the $profile->name.

I can get it to work, setting the value attribute like

```
{{ (old('name')) ? old('name') : $profile->name }}
```

Since I'm new to Laravel framework I want to know if there is a better way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `old($key, $default)`. It will return `$default` if `$key` is not found.